# How to get started with Flex and Java

Tags: java, apache-flex, ide

I want to learn Flex. I have some knowledge on Java Enterprise Edition, so the server side scripting is not very hard for me. But for Flex I am kind of lost. Unable to understand where to start. I am reading this [Flex Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/flex/index.htm). The IDE for Flash development is the Flash Builder. Also another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471871/best-ide-for-flex-development) says there is a free version of this software, but I guess the Flash Builder 4.7 Student edition is not free any more. I came to know that Eclipse has a Flex development plugin, but I don't know that, that plugin will serve the purpose.

It would very appreciative if someone give me pointers on the following topics.

1. Where to start on Flex 4,
2. Which IDE to use,
3. How to integrate with Web Service/EJB

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My one thing to add is that Flash Builder is an eclipse plugin.  I believe FlashDevelop can also be used; and Flash Develop is free.

Comment: It's a kind of oldish but I wrote [another answer regarding IDE's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384490/differences-between-adobe-actionscript-3-softwares-and-which-should-be-used-to-c/6384763#6384763). Right now I'd say IntelliJ is on top of the competition, but I have to say I don't know what the FDT team have been doing lately. FlashBuilder 4.7 is bug-ridden: stay away. Last time I checked (must be two years ago) FlashDevelop was very good for pure ActionScript development, but a no-go for big Flex projects. This is all, of course, just my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where to start on Flex 4 :**

Adobe website is the best place, here are few useful links:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/gumbo/flex_4_tutorials.pdf
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex.html

Apart from learning the basics of flex it will be good to learn the mvc frameworks used in flex, such as [Caringorm](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/cairngorm/home/Home/) and [PureMVC](http://puremvc.org/)

**Which IDE to use**: Adobe Flex Builder, they provide 60 day trial license, good enough to learn.

**How to integrate with Web Service/EJB** : There is something called HttpService in flex using which you can integrate with web services.